# Can't connect to Team Foundation Service

Tags: php, tfs, phpstorm, azure-devops

I have installed the TFS plugin for phpstrom 7, but I'm having a problem connecting to my account at Microsoft's Team Foundation Service (tfs.visualstudio.com).
After I looked for a solution, I have found out that I need to enable the alternate credentials in my user profile and it made a progress, but now I get an exception:

"org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexcepted sublement RelativeToString"

I'm not sure, but I think it has something to do with the https and not regular http request.

does anyone have a fix?

Thanks, Ben.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open bug logged in YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112210), please [follow](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23368682).